# Change font-size px to pt using regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

How could I change `font-size` value from `px` to `pt` keeping its numeric value the same using regular expression using php.

If I have

```
style = font-size:6px; line-height = 2px;
```

it would convert this like

```
style = font-size:6pt; line-height = 2px;
```

Comment: i think `str_replace` can do the trick 4 u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you need is `~font\-size: ?([\d]+)px~`:

```
$str = 'font-size: 6px; line-height: 12px';
echo preg_replace('~font\-size: ?([\d]+)px~', "font-size: $1pt", $str); // font-size: 6pt; line-height: 12px
```

Comment: Why use complicated regex though and not str_replace?

Comment: @because we want to replace just font-size, not all pixels to pts.